# JavaScript- how to see if an image has been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not sure of how to check if an image has been clicked in JavaScript and then alert() the reader something, *if* and *only* if the image has been clicked. Then, the reader will be sent to another webpage. I have all these components except from the image click check. Also, would JQuery be best for this? And if so, how do I implement it into HTML?

```
<a href="cca.html">
<img src="ccover.jpg" style="length:25%;width:25%"></img>
</a>
```

Comment: Where's your code? And what exactly do you want an "alert"? or "redirect to  different page"? on click on an image.

Comment: Bind click event to image, i don't see where is your issue???

Comment: Depends on your usage of JQuery, if you are just planning to use JQuery for this purpose i would suggest JavaScript over JQuery, if you are already using JQuery on page(same page) JQuery is better. So it depends.

Comment: @A. Wolff Thanks for the information, but can you elaborate on how to do so in the best way possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Javascript on Image Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114183/run-javascript-on-image-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML for pure JS**

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomethingOnClick()" >Click it</a>
```

**Pure JS**

```
function doSomethingOnClick (){ alert( 'Clicked it!' ); }
```

---

**HTML for JS Libraries**

For the JS libraries you need a  wrapping function to get the code working. It is good to know [when](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20303718/5594521) and [why](https://davidwalsh.name/6-reasons-to-use-javascript-libraries-frameworks) to use a JS library. If you have a little stuff that need to be handled by js then you shouldn't load tons of data that you will not use.

```
<a id="clicker" href="#" >Click it</a>
```

**[jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/click/)** *(My recomendation)*

```
$( '#clicker' ).click( function() { alert( 'Clicked it!' ); } );
```

**Dojo**

```
require(["dojo/on", "dojo/dom"], function(on, dom){ on( dom.byId("clicker"), "click", function(){ alert( 'Clicked it!' ); } ); });
```

**YUI**

```
$( '#clicker' ).on('click', function() { alert( 'Clicked it!' ); } );
```

**MooTools**

```
$( 'clicker' ).addEvent('click', function(){ alert('Clicked it!'); });
```

**Zepto**

```
$( '#clicker' ).on('click', function(){ alert( 'Clicked it!' ); });
```

**Prototype**

```
Event.observe( $('clicker'), 'click', function () { alert ('Clicked it!'); });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

No jQuery would not be 'best' here for such a simple requirement, it's 'best' when it saves time, effort, or processing power. This can be done easily with vanilla Javascript as follows:

**Code**

```
var image = document.getElementById("image");
image.onclick = function(e) {
  window.alert("Something");
  window.location.href = "www.anotherwebpage.com";
}
```

**Final Note**

Simple stuff here my friend, did you look for your question before asking it?

Comment: He asked if jQuery would be best for this. Consider my answer a 'no'. @VincentTeyssier

Comment: then he has both now ;)

Comment: @Andre Yes I looked for it, but nothing seemed to work for my code :(, but now I have so many answers, :)

Comment: LOL! (more stuff here because SO wants me to)

Answer (score 0):

1) assign an id to your image :

```
<img id="my_image" src="ccover.jpg" style="length:25%;width:25%"></img>
```

2) bind event click :

```
$('#my_image').click(function() {
     alert( "blabla" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can use the [$.fn.click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) and [window.location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp).

If you want to throw an alert whenever an image is clicked:

```
$('img').click(function() {
    alert('Image clicked!');
    window.location = 'http://example.com';
});
```

If you wish to act on a subset of images, add a class to your targeted images:

```
<img class="click-redirect" ...
```

and use it as your [selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

```
$('.click-redirect').click(function() { ... });
```

Comment: Think the author got what he was looking for and peace'd. Thanks for the post though

Comment: @AndrueAnderson, education through examples AND docs is better than examples only, imho.

Comment: Your random thought seems correct to me too, thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Andre Laptop off, phone silent! By still, great array of useful answers!